# Scikit learn installation

Tags: scikit-learn

I tried to install scikit learn on my Ubuntu device using the command :
pip install -U scikit-learn

I already have numpy, scipy and matpotlib installed. 
I am getting the following error:
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import RequirementParseError
ImportError: cannot import name RequirementParseError

Comment: Edit your question and add information about your system. Are you on windows ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Can you execute, `python -c "import sys, scipy, numpy, pip; print(scipy.__version__, numpy.__version__, pip.__version__, sys.version_info)"`, and add the result to your question?

Comment: @Newbie just posted a possible solution since you use ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the console:

```
sudo -i
```

Type your password and then type:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked! Is there any reason why pip didn't work?

Comment: @Newbie yes. Using sudo -i you have root rights. It's safer to install like this